# Going out in Rummikub using a joker from my rack

Tags: rummikub, joker

Other posts on the rules for using the a joker don't cover the following scenario:

It's near the end of a game. I have only one tile left in my rack. It's my turn & I cannot go out, so I draw a tile from the bag. This tile is a joker. My tile is, say, a red 5. When it comes to my turn again, there is a meld on the table that is a run of red 1,2,3. Can I use the joker on my rack as a red 4 and add my existing red 5 to the run & declare Rummikub?

The rules seem to imply that you can only use a joker from your rack with two other tiles, also in your rack to make a meld, but at the end of game you do not have sufficient tiles to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Lucky you! From [this version of the rules](https://tesera.ru/images/items/784463/Rummikub_Rules.pdf), it's clear that you can use a joker from your rack that you've drawn as any single tile without other restrictions. The restriction that requires you to use it with two other tiles only applies when you use a joker that you've retrieved from the table.

> A joker can be retrieved from a set on the table by a player who can replace it during his turn with a tile of the same numerical value and color it represents. ...  A joker that has been replaced must be used in the player's same turn with 2 or more tiles from his rack to make a new set.